# Strange scaling behavior

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have my own class that holds a sprite.

The sprite is an animation made with Zwoptex. I got both retina and standard images alright.

I put my class in middle of the scene. And, for some reason, the sprite displays with a really small size.

I thought it might be because of scaling (although I never scale the sprite). So I decided to put two NSLogs:

```
    NSLog(@"%f",enemy2.scale);
    NSLog(@"%f",enemy2.sprite.scale);
```

One tells me the scale of my custom class itself and the other the scale of the sprite itself.

However, when I put ***those two lines of code***,  ***the sprite appears with the expected size (bigger)***.

And the NSLog result is 1.0.

Why? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the scale getter method has been implemented and changes the scale_ instance variable this should not happen.

Initially I would say that the sprites being small size seems to indicate that you are loading the SD images on a Retina device, instead of the HD images. Be sure to name your SD and HD assets like this if you're using a texture atlas:

```
// SD images
textureatlas.png
textureatlas.plist
--> player.png
--> enemy.png

// HD images
textureatlas-hd.png
textureatlas-hd.plist
--> player.png       // no -HD suffix!
--> enemy.png        // no -HD suffix!
```

It is a common mistake to also suffix the sprite frames inside the texture atlas. So if your sprite frames in the HD texture atlas are named `player-hd.png` and `enemy-hd.png` then Cocos2D will not find them and reverts to loading the SD images.

It should be noted that [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.de) will detect and can automatically correct this for you. Last time I used [Zwoptex](http://www.zwoptexapp.com), it would allow you to create such incorrect texture atlases.